# SQL: How to search for a substring except in cases where that substring is a part of a specific word?

Tags: sql

Say that there are rows which contain the following texts 'med', 'medical', 'med medical'.

I want to retrieve all rows which contain the substring 'med' except if that substring is part of the string 'abc medical def'.

My desired result is to only retrieve 'med' and 'med medical' because they contain the substring 'med' and that substring is not a part of 'medical'.

I can use `LIKE 'med%'` but that would retrieve all 3.

Comment: What SQL database are you using?

Comment: google big query

Comment: You edited the question, yesterday your requirement was different. Please provide examples of the rows and which ones you need to retrieve exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another condition:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'med%' AND field <> 'medical';
```

Comment: Is there something that would exclude 'abc medical def' ?

Comment: same thing just add `AND field <> 'abc medical def'` if there are a lot of cases you could use `NOT IN ('medical', 'abc medical def', 'no medical')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Like `'med%'` that will return data where field starts with `med`. It will exclude other data. So you can use :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'med%' AND field != 'medical'
```